# Tips to make a application multiplatform like Discord

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

I wanna try to make an application like Discord (Groups/Add Friends/Voice Call/Video Call/Streaming) and until now I was focus on messages and on an application for Web(ReactJS or any) and PC/Mac/Linux(ElectronJS or any), and working on backend with NodeJS/ExpressJS/Socket.IO/GraphQL/MongoDB. Recently got a solution for Voice Call and Video Call which is PeerJS, but now I asked myself how would this work in Androd/iOS application? Am I choosing well my frameworks and language? Because of course one Android/iOS user have to be able to join to a Voice/Video with users on PC/Web Is there other frameworks?  Not just for Voice/Video Call, all the application. Can anyone please share some documentation or tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A personal tip would be to refrain from using PeerJS, as it doesn’t support VP8 Simulcast. When creating high-load group video calling software like discord, you need VP8 Simulcast because it splits a stream into different bitrates for different users, dependent on their bandwidth and that of the person streaming.

Consider reading about WebRTC in JS WebAPI! Unfortunately, the main issue nowadays is hosting a Signalling server (which essentially manages who is where in terms of rooms) and TURN Servers (which gets information such as the IP address of a user joining a room).

In terms of the iOS app, and Android App, consider implementing with a language of your choice, such as Xamarin.

Personally, I prefer React Native for mobile applications. Take a look at it online!

Good luck in your venture!